# Are these conditions equivalent for ultrafilters on topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, limits, set-theory, filters

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $F$ be an [ultrafilter](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ultrafilter) on $X$. Denote
$$
\cap F := \bigcap_{S\in F} S .
$$

Let now $x\in X$. Let $N(x)$ be the [neighborhood filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system) of $x$, i.e. the set of all open sets containing $x$.

Are the following conditions equivalent?

1. $x\in\cap F$.
2. $N(x)\subseteq F$.

If not, are the above equivalent if we require that $X$ be compact Hausdorff?

Comment: The two conditions are not equivalent in general.

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are elements of a topological space $X$ such that $\{x\}$ is open, but every neighbourhood of $y$ contains $x$, then $x\in\cap N(y)$, however $N(x)\not\subseteq N(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

No in general: if $\mathcal{F}$ is any free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ in the cofinite topology, then 2, holds for any $x$, as any cofinite set is in $\mathcal{F}$, but $\bigcap \mathcal{F}=\emptyset$. So 2 implies 1 can fail, even for compact spaces.

But that example is only compact $T_1$, and in any space 1. implies 2, just by the superset property of filters. If $X$ is compact $T_2$ and $\mathcal{N}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ then suppose $F \in \mathcal{F}$. Then any open set containing $x$ intersects $F$ (both are in $\mathcal{F}$), so $x \in \overline{F}$. Hence $x \in \bigcap \{\overline{F}: F \in \mathcal{F}\}$. Now try to reason why $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$ too.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=[0,1]$ with the usual topology. Let $F$ be any ultrafilter on $[0,1]$ extending the cofinite filter $C$ on $\{\frac1n:n=1,2,3,\dots\}$. Every neighborhood of $0$ contains all but finitely many of the $\frac1n$ and is therefore in $F$. But the set $[0,1]-\{0\}$ contains all the $\frac1n$ and is therefore also in $F$. So $\bigcap F$ doesn't contain $0$. Thus, your statement 2 holds for $x=0$ but statement 1 does not.

In general, statement 1 says that $F$ is the principal ultrafilter generated by $\{x\}$ while statement 2 says that $F$ converges to $x$. My example is just the simplest case of a convergent, non-principal ultrafilter.